# How do I look up Java Components in Mule?

Tags: java, mule

Given a Java Component like the one below

```
<flow name="MainFlow2" doc:name="MainFlow2">
    ...
    <component class="com.service.gateway.MyService" doc:name="My Gateway"/>
    ...
</flow>
```

I'm trying to get it while registering a custom agent

```
<custom-agent name="my-agent" class="com.monitor.MyAgent"/>
```

by doing this

```
 muleContext.getRegistry().lookupObjects(DefaultJavaComponent.class);
```

Looks like these java components are not in the registry, I'm not getting them.

So far I have this workaround

```
    // Get all flows
    for (AbstractFlowConstruct flowConstruct : muleContext.getRegistry().lookupObjects(AbstractFlowConstruct.class)) {
           if (flowConstruct instanceof AbstractPipeline) {
                 //get flow's MessageProcessor
                 List<MessageProcessor> mgs = ((AbstractPipeline) flowConstruct).getMessageProcessors();
                 for (MessageProcessor messageProcessor : mgs) {
                           if (messageProcessor instanceof DefaultJavaComponent) {
                              DefaultJavaComponent javaComp = (DefaultJavaComponent) messageProcessor;
                              //GOT IT!
                           }
                 }
            }
      }
```

Do you know how to directly get all Java Components programmatically?

Comment: I've run some tests and every component is registered in the registry correctly. What classes/interfaces does your component extend/implement?

Comment: @genjosanzo none, they are POJOs. In which of the registries are they?

Comment: so they probably won't be registered as DefaultJavaComponent. Have you tried to lookup for them directly (e.g.  muleContext.getRegistry().lookupObjects(MyService.class) )?

Comment: that could work but I do not know in advance what are the classes deployed as components. I'm trying to build something generic that will pick up all java comp automatically. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

DefaultJavaComponent is a Mule wrapper that is used to adapt any POJO as a usable component, this is why you won't find it registered.

Personally, for this kind of advanced scenario, I would use Spring to instantiate my POJOs, refer to them as `spring-object`s in `component` and look them up in `muleContext.getRegistry()` using whatever strategy makes sense (by name? by class?).

Comment: The thing is that I want to get the wrapper, looking by name or class will return the POJO instance.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood, I thought you wanted the POJO instances.